# In SQL, how to collapse two rows into one?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I have the following table:

| C1 | C2 | C3 | C4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alton | James | Webs | AltonJamesWebs |
| Alton | Webs | Jams | AltonJamsWebs |
| Buddarakh | Izme | Grill | BuddarakhGrillIzme |
| Buddarakh | Gri | Izmezh | BuddarakhGriIzmezh |

How would I collapse the table based on the Column C1 so that the result looks like the following:

| C1 | C2_1 | C3_1 | C4_1 | C2_2 | C3_2 | C4_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alton | James | Webs | AltonJamesWebs | Webs | Jams | AltonJamsWebs |
| Buddarakh | Izme | Grill | BuddarakhGrillIzme | Gri | Izmezh | BuddarakhGriIzmezh |

The ultimate purpose of this is to calculate the Levensthein Distance between the strings in columns C4_1 and C4_2.

Comment: A PIVOT would do this, but it will have its limits with regards to columns.

Comment: Do you always have exactly 2 rows you are combining?

Comment: @DaleK I would say yes. But, to be more frugal, there might be cases where there are more than 2 rows.

Comment: How many max? You have to know in advance to be able to handle it.

Comment: @DaleK For the sake of simplicity, it is two.

Comment: @DaleK I used Patrick's solution below. It seems to work.

Comment: @DaleK https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dv_bBSodPB0&ab_channel=TrillSouljah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting your example data into DDL/DML:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (C1 NVARCHAR(20), C2 NVARCHAR(20), C3 NVARCHAR(20), C4 NVARCHAR(20));
INSERT INTO @Table (C1, C2, C3, C4) VALUES
('Alton     ', 'James   ', 'Webs    ', 'AltonJamesWebs    '),
('Alton     ', 'Webs    ', 'Jams    ', 'AltonJamsWebs     '),
('Buddarakh ', 'Izme    ', 'Grill   ', 'BuddarakhGrillIzme'),
('Buddarakh ', 'Gri     ', 'Izmezh  ', 'BuddarakhGriIzmezh'),
('Buddarakh ', 'Gric    ', 'Izmezh  ', 'BuddarakhGriIzmezh');
```

We can perform a self-join, but first we'll want to assign some row numbers so we can keep track of the rows later:

```
;WITH nowWithRowNumber AS (
SELECT t.C1, t.C2, t.C3, t.C4, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY C1 ORDER BY c2, c3, c4) AS rn
  FROM @Table t
)

SELECT t.C1, t.C2, t.c3, t.C4, t2.C2 AS C2_2, t2.C3 AS C3_2, t2.C4 AS C4_2, t2.rn
  FROM nowWithRowNumber t
    INNER JOIN nowWithRowNumber t2
      ON t.C1 = t2.C1
      AND t2.rn <> 1
      AND (
               t.c2 <> t2.c2
            OR t.c3 <> t2.c3
          ) 
 WHERE t.rn = 1
```

```
C1              C2          c3          C4                  C2_2        C3_2        C4_2                rn
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Alton           James       Webs        AltonJamesWebs      Webs        Jams        AltonJamsWebs       2
Buddarakh       Gri         Izmezh      BuddarakhGriIzmezh  Gric        Izmezh      BuddarakhGriIzmezh  2
Buddarakh       Gri         Izmezh      BuddarakhGriIzmezh  Izme        Grill       BuddarakhGrillIzme  3
```

This assumes the logic which you'll need to confirm or tune, that the rows should join based on the fact that the c1 columns match, but the others do not, and that the rows should be partition on c1 and sorted on c2, c3, c4.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to understand the wider context of your problem here, I think this is an x,y problem. In my experience when I have wanted to calculate the Levenshtein Distance I have been attempting to find duplicate rows, and I've always wanted to do something with them once found. Pivoting them into columns actually makes any further processing very difficult. So I would approach this by keeping the rows as they are, but matching them against the first duplicate in the C1 group found. This also handles as many potential duplicates as are found - although to be fair this is fairly simplistic logic.

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (Id int, C1 nvarchar(20), C2 nvarchar(20), C3 nvarchar(20), C4 nvarchar(20));

INSERT INTO @Table (Id, C1, C2, C3, C4) VALUES
(1, 'Alton', 'James', 'Webs', 'AltonJamesWebs'),
(2, 'Alton', 'Webs', 'Jams', 'AltonJamsWebs'),
(3, 'Buddarakh', 'Izme', 'Grill', 'BuddarakhGrillIzme'),
(4, 'Buddarakh', 'Gri', 'Izmezh', 'BuddarakhGriIzmezh'),
(5, 'Buddarakh', 'Gric', 'Izmezh', 'BuddarakhGriIzmezh');

WITH cte1 AS (
    -- First find the row number within the C1 group
    SELECT *
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY C1 ORDER BY Id) rn 
    FROM @Table
), cte2 AS (
    -- Second using lag for all but the first row, lag back using rn to the
    -- first row in the C1 group
    SELECT *
        , CASE WHEN rn > 1 THEN LAG(Id, rn-1, null) OVER (PARTITION BY C1 ORDER BY Id) ELSE NULL END baseId
        , CASE WHEN rn > 1 THEN LAG(C2, rn-1, null) OVER (PARTITION BY C1 ORDER BY Id) ELSE NULL END baseC2
        , CASE WHEN rn > 1 THEN LAG(C3, rn-1, null) OVER (PARTITION BY C1 ORDER BY Id) ELSE NULL END baseC3
        , CASE WHEN rn > 1 THEN LAG(C4, rn-1, null) OVER (PARTITION BY C1 ORDER BY Id) ELSE NULL END baseC4
    FROM cte1
)
SELECT Id
    , C1, C2, C3, C4
    , baseId, baseC2, baseC3, baseC4
    -- Some function to calculate Levenshtein Distance
    , dbo.LevenshteinDistance(baseC4, C4) LevenshteinDistance
FROM cte2;
```

This returns:

| Id | C1 | C2 | C3 | C4 | baseId | baseC2 | baseC3 | baseC4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Alton | James | Webs | AltonJamesWebs | null | null | null | null |
| 2 | Alton | Webs | Jams | AltonJamsWebs | 1 | James | Webs | AltonJamesWebs |
| 3 | Buddarakh | Izme | Grill | BuddarakhGrillIzme | null | null | null | null |
| 4 | Buddarakh | Gri | Izmezh | BuddarakhGriIzmezh | 3 | Izme | Grill | BuddarakhGrillIzme |
| 5 | Buddarakh | Gric | Izmezh | BuddarakhGriIzmezh | 3 | Izme | Grill | BuddarakhGrillIzme |

Which as you can see returns against each row (aside from the first in the group), the details of the first row in the group which can then be used to calculate the Levenshtein Distance and then potentially to merge them because it knows which rows its being compared against.

[DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/_fELjozM)

Thanks for the sample data Patrick Hurst.

Note you might also consider the [`DIFFERENCE` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/difference-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)